# Can any one make this jquery code small

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created jquery code but this is very big. please can any make small and dynamic code.

Jquery code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menuone').hover(
  function() {
    $('.bg-imgsection').toggleClass('displayon');
    $('#logo .log-bg').toggleClass('log-bg1');
  }
);
$('#menutwo').hover(
  function() {
    $('.bg-imgsection2').toggleClass('displayon');
    $('#logo .log-bg').toggleClass('log-bg1');
  }
);
$('#menuthree').hover(
  function() {
    $('.bg-imgsection3').toggleClass('displayon');
    $('#logo .log-bg').toggleClass('log-bg1');
  }
);
$('#menufour').hover(
  function() {
    $('.bg-imgsection4').toggleClass('displayon');
    $('#logo .log-bg').toggleClass('log-bg1');
  }
);

});
```

here is [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/qwm6e49x/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a common handler and use an object to refer the class based on `id` of the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // object for refering the class based on id
  var cls = {
    menuone: 1,
    menutwo: 2,
    menuthree: 3,
    menufour: 4
  };

  $('#menuone,#menutwo,#menuthree,#menufour').hover(function() {
    // generate classname using id and the object
    $('.bg-imgsection' + cls[this.id]).toggleClass('displayon');
    $('#logo .log-bg').toggleClass('log-bg1');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using different ids. Put a common class say .`.menu` to each `menu div` and change the jQuery script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.menu').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.bg-imgsection').toggleClass('displayon');
        $(this).find('#logo .log-bg').toggleClass('log-bg1');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add class selector to your html and use it like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.className').hover(function() {
    $('.bg-imgsectionAll').toggleClass('displayon');
    $('#logo .log-bg').toggleClass('log-bg1');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can do this by.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mymenu_hover_effects').hover(
  function() {
    var show_div=$(this).attr('data-show-section');
    $('.'+show_div).toggleClass('displayon');
    $('#logo .log-bg').toggleClass('log-bg1');
  }
);
});
```

```css
.displayon{
  display:block;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-area">
  <div id="logo">
   <div class="log-txt animated fadeInUp"><img src="images/big-logo.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="log-bg"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="menuone"  data-show-section="bg-imgsection" class="mymenu_hover_effects">
   <div class="bg-imgsection animated fadeIn"><img src="images/our-group.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a1">
    <a href="index.html">
     <h1>Our Group Companies</h1>
     <p>Our complete communication management solution has
       over 14 components to enhance any business operation.</p>
      </a>
   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="menutwo" data-show-section="bg-imgsection2" class="mymenu_hover_effects">
   <div class="bg-imgsection2 animated fadeIn"><img src="https://cdn.img42.com/9f63b03c6c1aa61a04710be5316a3275.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a2">
    <a href="#">
     <h1>About Asergis Group</h1>
     <p>With over 15 years’ experience, the Asergis Group has a proven track record in the telecoms’ industry. We take great pride in what we do and we combine a wealth of global expertise and first-rate customer care to offer competitively priced products and services.</p>
    </a>
   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="menuthree"  data-show-section="bg-imgsection3" class="mymenu_hover_effects">
   <div class="bg-imgsection3 animated fadeIn"><img src="images/social.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a3">
    <div class="soical">
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss" title="blog"></i></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
     <h1>Social Responsibility</h1>
     <p>We aim to make a positive impact on society and leave a
     small footprint on the environment.</p>
    </a>
   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="menufour"  data-show-section="bg-imgsection4" class="mymenu_hover_effects">
   <div class="bg-imgsection4 animated fadeIn"><img src="images/investor.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a4">
    <a href="#">
     <h1>Investor Relations</h1>
     <p>Our investors are our greatest asset. Our success relies on our
     ability to attract, develop.</p>
    </a>
   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="menufive">
   <div class="bg-imgsection5 animated fadeIn"><img src="images/media.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a5">
    <a href="#">
     <h1>Media/News</h1>
     <p>We aim to make a positive impact on society and leave a
     small footprint on the environment.</p>
    </a>
   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="menusix">
   <div class="bg-imgsection6 animated fadeIn"><img src="images/careers.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a6">
    <a href="#">
     <h1>Careers</h1>
     <p>Our natural resources play an essential role in
     people’s everyday lives.</p>
    </a>
   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="menuseven">
   <div class="bg-imgsection7 animated fadeIn"><img src="images/cantact.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a7">
    <a href="#">
     <h1>Contact Us</h1>
     <p>Asergis have made significant investment and
     expansion into their contacts.</p>
    </a>
    <div class="contact-div">
     <div class="flag">
      <span id="uk" class="scaleimg"><img src="images/uk-flag.jpg" alt=""></span>
      <span id="china"><img src="images/china-flag.jpg" alt=""></span>
      <span id="india"><img src="images/india-flag.jpg" alt=""></span>
      <span id="malta"><img src="images/malta-flag.jpg" alt=""></span>
     </div>
     <div class="cont-address">
      <ul class="uk">
       <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Walker House, <br>
       375 Mitcham Road, Croydon, <br>
       Surrey, CR0 3HP, <br>
       United Kingdom</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="china">
       <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> China, <br>
       Address go here</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="india">
       <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 705-707 Vishwa Sadan Building <br>
        9 District Centre <br>
        Janak Puri, New Delhi <br>
        110058, India</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="malta">
       <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> First Floor Office 1 <br>
       Mompalao Buildings <br>
       Triq it Torri (Tower Road) <br>
       Msida , MSD 1825, <br> Malta</li>
      </ul>
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="menueight">
   <div class="bg-imgsection8 animated fadeIn"><img src="images/careers.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a8">
    <a href="#">
     <h1>Global PoP Locations</h1>
     <p>Strategically placed PoPs allow Asergis to give you a wider choice of new and highly competitive services.</p>
    </a>
   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="menunine">
   <div class="bg-imgsection9 animated fadeIn"><img src="images/careers.png" alt=""></div>
   <div class="contant-banner-area animated fadeInUp a9">
    <a href="#">
     <h1>Resellers</h1>
     <p>Sell the full range of Asergis Telecom products to your customers. As an Asergis Telecom Reseller.</p>
    </a>
   </div>   
  </div>

 </div>
```

You need to add a 'data-' attribute in HTML and then get that attribute in Jquery to set classes or attributes you want to set for a specific div. I have did this for first four elemennts with id menu* in your example. you can modify this according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('div[id^=menu]')` to select all `div` whose ID begins with 'menu'.

And because the *'bg-imgsection'* div is the first child of the *'menu'* div (according to your JSFiddle), you then can use this selector in the event handler: `$(':first-child', this)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[id^=menu]').hover(function() {
    $(':first-child', this).toggleClass('displayon');
  });
});
```

```css
div { width:100px; margin-right:2px; background-color:#eee; cursor:default; float:left }
.displayon { background-color:#bcd }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuone">Menu One<div class="bg-imgsection1">Section #1</div></div>
<div id="menutwo">Menu Two<div class="bg-imgsection2">Section #2</div></div>
<div id="menuthree">Menu Three<div class="bg-imgsection3">Section #3</div></div>
<div id="menufour">Menu Four<div class="bg-imgsection4">Section #4</div></div>
```